# How to uniquely identify devices connected to the GW in Thingsboard

Tags: device, thingsboard, identify

I am using ThingsBoard (https://thingsboard.io/) version 3.4.1, OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I know how to connect devices to the Thingsboard and send data and creating dashboard etc. Previously I had connected my GW to the Thingsboard with which only one device was attached. But if more than one devices are attached to one GW (the usual case) how to uniquely identify the devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Device name should be unique.

Each time gateway sends data on behalf of real device gateway adds to data the name of real device.